# Instrumental waltz music used in old "Popeye" cartoon (unknown music from 30's or earlier)

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack, instrumental

I have an animated video featuring waltz music: [Popeye COLORIZED 007 "The Dance Contest" (November 23, 1934)](https://youtu.be/DukI4QcRCCQ?t=53s).

It looks similar to The Ink Spots' *With Plenty Of Money And You*, but it isn't it.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> George Melachrino - The Champagne Waltz

in a bad quality: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wA-Z6aZLQ9g

There is a good version in i.e. Spotify. Anyway... this is the song.